# Webview cant get acces to location

Tags: java, android, webview

I made android app that will only open website and so far everything works great except that my app doesn't give acces to user location. In my website I have button "Get user location" and when I open website from my phone using chrome it works great but on mobile app it does not.

Here is my code that I used watching some youtube videos. I have no experience with android apps at all.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mediasky;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("my website link");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mediasky">

    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Mediasky">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **WebChromeClient**:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
});
```

`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permissions are required.

Check [AdvancedWebview](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) for reference

Comment: Does the webview client also do Android runtime permissions?  Because that's lacking in their code as well.

Comment: No you have to manually add permissions. Check this gist to easily manage runtime permissions. https://gist.github.com/zeero0/fd314a281d007283fc7931f1c5da634c

Comment: @Zeero0 but where do I need to add that code? I have 0 knowledge of android programming